# Ubuntu 14.04.1 - Strange color depth

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, color-depth

Hi I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 with Nvidia Drivers. Acceleration works without a problem.

But the problem is that I can see strange color depth even when color depth is set to 24 bit. I know the difference between Windows's RGBA and RGB In Ubuntu so I know that 32 bit RGBA is basically 24 bit RGB in Ubuntu.

I don’t know why the screen is showing such poor colors. Maybe it is just in my eyes but I can see it everywhere in Ubuntu while colors in Windows are okay.

Screenshots:

[image]
[image]

My graphic's specs are:

Lenovo y510p nvidia 755m x2 SLI

I tried to adjust digital vibrancy and it helped a bit and colors looked vibrant but I still see for example a shadow around windows when moved over a white background.

I tried basically every NVidia driver version including the newest one but with the same result.

Note that my laptop also has an Integrated Intel Graphics but it is switched on only when the second GPU is removed from the Ultrabay or in Windows 8 when I unplug the power source, so I don’t know much how Optimus technology works in Ubuntu but I am pretty sure it's not even used because it is not listed in VGA/3D device list when asked in terminal, only the two Nvidia cards are listed.

Comment: It would help to post and compare screenshots, one performed by the operating system (to see how the system thinks the screen looks), and one taken with an external camera.

Comment: I have a screenshot but at the moment I dont have very good camera so you wont see much. I will add a screenshot.

Comment: The screenshots "from the inside" look fine here and, since you say the colours are fine on Windows, it's no hardware issue with the screen or something. What artefacts do you think are not supposed to be there? The window shadow is rendered by Unity/compiz in the default settings.

Comment: Please use a camera as I can’t see anything wrong with the screen shots you provided...

Comment: @JanSelep mark an answer please.

Answer (score 8):

I have the same laptop except with dual GT 750Ms. I have just managed to solve this issue.

### The solution:

1. Go into the `nvidia-settings` utility.
2. Click on the section for your laptop display (mine was DFP-1-(LGD)).
3. Go to the *`Controls`* tab.
4. Under *`Dithering Controls`* there will be a *`Depth`* option. Mine was set to Auto and had two further options: 8 bpc and 6 bpc. Changing it to 6 bpc instantly solved the funny colour gradients that made it look like it was running at a 16-bit colour depth.

I hope this helped solved your issue. Maybe someone more knowledgeable can explain why this works and why 8 bpc looks worse than 6 bpc.

Comment: Additionally do not forget to actually set the drop box titled "Dithering" to "Enabled"

Answer (score 2):

I was having this same issue with my old `GeForce 9500 GT` on Ubuntu 18.04 and the [solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/588232/55128) mentioned by Billal did not work. In my case I had to:

1. Go into the nvidia-settings utility.
2. Click on the section for your laptop display.
3. Go to the Controls tab.
4. Under `Color Controls` there will be a `Color range` option. Mine was set to
   `Full` and changing it to `Limited` instantly solved the problem.

Comment: I was trying to understand why ubuntu so strange influence for my eyes. Set color range to limited and feel comfortable all colors now