# [14.10]Colour Banding with proprietary Nvidia drivers GT750M

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 14.10, color-depth

I have a colour banding issue on Ubuntu 14.10. It only occurs on the proprietary drivers, and is fairly noticeable. I am currently using driver version 331.113. The colour banding does not appear on the Nouveau driver. The laptop I'm using is the Lenovo Ideapad Y510p with a GT750M card, on a new install of Ubuntu 14.10. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer to this issue. Changing the dithering depth from auto to 6bpc solves the issue. I found the answer in this thread. [Ubuntu 14.04.1 - Strange color depth](https://askubuntu.com/questions/582111/ubuntu-14-04-1-strange-color-depth)

> I have the same laptop except with dual GT 750Ms. I have just managed
>   to solve this issue.
>
> The solution:
>
> 1. Go into the nvidia-settings utility.
> 2. Click on the section for your laptop display (mine was DFP-1-(LGD)).
> 3. Go to the Controls tab.
> 4. Under Dithering Controls there will be a Depth option. Mine was set to Auto and had two further options: 8 bpc and 6 bpc. Changing it
>      to 6 bpc instantly solved the funny colour gradients that made it look
>      like it was running at a 16-bit colour depth.
>
> I hope this helped solved your issue. Maybe someone more knowledgeable
>   can explain why this works and why 8 bpc looks worse than 6 bpc.

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... :-( Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! ;-) You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...